# bluetooth isnt working on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Tried couple of solution to fix this issue but nothing worked so far.

Here is the output for `rfkill list`

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I try `bluetoothctl`, this what I get:

```
hozayfa@hozayfa:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power off
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

output for `dmesg | grep Blue`

```
hozayfa@hozayfa:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[   89.501965] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   89.501993] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   89.501997] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   89.501999] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   89.502005] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  389.448413] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  389.448415] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  389.448418] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e091]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208BM [GeForce 920M] [10de:1299] (rev a1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b51f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 258a:1007  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line shows BT as poweroff

> [bluetooth]# power off

Check if your computer has a physical switch to turn it on, or check bios if there's a way to power it on and off.

Drivers for this card are supposed to be supported. It seems to be down.

Comment: That has put me off for a while. I was using windows and it was working normally.

Comment: Take a look to this post [link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-bluetooth-dont-discovers-device-bluetoothctl-no-default-controller/90699)